# Javascript can't set colour

Tags: javascript, function, object

The function is called via:

```
myChart.gChangeBarColour(1, "#000000");
```

This works:

```
   // Changes bars colour
    this.gChangeBarColour = function(gBarID, gBarColour) {

        if (gBarID <= this.gData.length && gBarID >= 0) {

            document.getElementById("gBar" + gBarID).style.backgroundColor = '#000000';

        }

    }
```

But this doesn't work:

```
// Changes bars colour
this.gChangeBarColour = function(gBarID, gBarColour) {

    if (gBarID <= this.gData.length && gBarID >= 0) {

        document.getElementById("gBar" + gBarID).style.backgroundColor = '" + gBarColour + "';

    }

}
```

No errors in the console at all!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `'" + gBarColour + "'`  is a `string` , delimited by single quotes `'` that contains `" + gBarColour + "`, that value is then used as the color.

You need to leave out all the quotes and plus signs:

```
// assign the value of gBarColour to the backgroundColor property
document.getElementById("gBar" + gBarID).style.backgroundColor = gBarColour;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'" + gBarColour + "'
```

should be

`gBarColour` or `''+gBarColour`